# WaitCommEvent compatible with pipes?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am working with legacy C++/MFC/Win32 code.  The project multiplexes various serial protocols over separate physical serial ports, one per client system, to a common front end data repository.

Since the program was originally designed to communicate over serial ports there are many assumptions in the code as far as setup and management of serial events go: ACK/NAK transport verification, inner-byte delay checks, etc…

The existing architecture leverages overlapped reads and writes with event notification via WaitCommEvent.

I have been tasked to add another client interface, using a single client pipe server; which, like the serial ports, will support one client per “file”.

In reading the docs for WaitCommEvent it looks like it was designed to work with OS abstracted physical communications devices; like serial ports.

The simple question, can I leverage the existing serial skewed “wait” model to work with a pipe, or should I go ahead and virtualize it so that it can be overridden it with specific pipe logic?

Thanks to those (the minority for sure) of developers who know what I am asking.

Comment: No, serial ports only.  Pipes are much simpler, WaitForSingleObject() on an OVERLAPPED.hEvent gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a good reference right now, but it is my understanding that WaitCommEvent only works with communications resources and that a pipe is not defined to be a communications resource in the same sense as e.g. a serial port. WaitCommEvent waits for the underlying driver to set certain bit-flags, like when new characters arrive, and I don't believe pipes (or files) work that way internally.